# Blink animation cause view stuck

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to create a method for blink some icon in my app.
But when I'm using this code:

```
-(void)blinkIcon : (UIButton *)theIcon
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 6 ; i++)
  {
    if (theIcon.hidden)
    {
        theIcon.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        theIcon.hidden = YES;
    }
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.3]];
  }
  theIcon.hidden = NO;
}
```

It's not working so well because the icon is "stuck" for a few sec and that's it.
the process have to end with:

```
theIcon.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to blink a button? clarify blink please.

Comment: Yes, the button is doing something. I just want to make him blink when something in the app have a new update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote this method that takes a button does what I *think* you mean by *blink*.

```
- (void)blinkButton:(UIButton *)button {
    CGFloat newAlpha = button.alpha == 1.0 ? 0.1 : 1.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        button.alpha = newAlpha;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self blinkButton:button];
    }];
}
```

It produces the following result:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/48vfpgn1cw6mj17/blink2.mov?dl=0

If you wan't to be able to stop it at some future point, you can do something like this - I set up a bar button item for testing that calls the stopBlinking method:

```
- (void)blinkButton:(UIButton *)button {
    // if we shouldn't be blinking and the button is currently not
    // totally faded in, fade it all the way in
    if (!_shouldBlink && button.alpha != 1.0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            button.alpha = 1.0;
        }];
    }

    // otherwise we should continue blinking
    else {
        CGFloat newAlpha = button.alpha == 1.0 ? 0.1 : 1.0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            button.alpha = newAlpha;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self blinkButton:button];
        }];
    }
}

- (void)stopBlinking {
    _shouldBlink = NO;
}
```

That produces this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbwol1ac710t6nw/stop.mov?dl=0

Comment: It's looks great, but it will blink forever like this, am I right?

Comment: I need it to blink a few times and then it will stop.

Comment: See my edit for the ability to stop. There are many ways to accomplish this, but this is the first I came up with. Just make sure when you want to start blinking the button you set the _shouldBlink instance variable to YES.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to make it stop automatically ? lets say after 4 blinks?

Comment: Yes, you might need to add a counter NSInteger or something to track how many times it blinks after you tell it to stop, and every time it blinks after you tell it to stop you decrement it, once the counter reaches 0 stop it. If my answer helped, I'd appreciate you accepting it.